# Change values in dataframe by condition: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, rstudio

Sorry, I could not find right answer in questions with ***longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length***
I have a dataframe like this

```
dt = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), A=c('a', 'a', 'c', 'b','b'), B= c('d', 'd','h', 'd', 'd'))
```

And I want to get

```
  id A B final
1  1 a d  <NA>
2  2 a d     d
3  3 c h     c
4  4 b d     b
5  5 b d     d
```

I do

```
dt$A = ifelse(dt$A[dt$id] == dt$A[dt$id-1], as.character(dt$B[dt$id-1]), as.character(dt$A))
Warning message:
In dt$A[dt$id] == dt$A[dt$id - 1] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I can do

```
shift <- function(x, n){
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}

dt$sht <- shift(as.character(dt$A), 1)
dt$new = ifelse(dt$sht == dt$A, as.character(dt$B), as.character(dt$A[dt$id+1]))
temp = dt$new 
temp=append(NA, temp)
temp = temp[-6]
dt$final = temp
dt[, c(1,2,3,6)]

  id A B final
1  1 a d  <NA>
2  2 a d     d
3  3 c h     c
4  4 b d     b
5  5 b d     d
```

But it is a long way, I think you can correct the error in the formula

```
dt$A = ifelse(dt$A[dt$id] == dt$A[dt$id-1], as.character(dt$B[dt$id-1]), as.character(dt$A))
```

Or I will be grateful for any more convenient and shorter way.

Comment: `ifelse` requires all the arguments to be same length.  From your code, it doesn't look like `dt$A[dt$id-1]`  what would be the value when `dt$id` is 1.  `R` indexing starts from 1.  It created the issue.  I think what you need is `ifelse(dt$A == lag(dt$A), `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing in `R` starts from 1.  When we take `dt$id -1`, for the 'id =1, it becomes 0 and indexing with that returns

```
dt$A[0]
#character(0)
```

resulting in a difference in the `length` of different arguments of `ifelse`.

> ifelse(test, yes, no)
>
> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.

---

Instead, we can make use of `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
    mutate(final = case_when(A == lag(A, default = A[1]) ~ lag(B), TRUE ~ A))
#  id A B final
#1  1 a d  <NA>
#2  2 a d     d
#3  3 c h     c
#4  4 b d     b
#5  5 b d     d
```

Here, it can be replaced with `ifelse` too, and according to `?case_when`

> This function allows you to vectorise multiple if_else() statements.

#### data

```
dt = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), A=c('a', 'a', 'c', 'b','b'), 
   B= c('d', 'd','h', 'd', 'd'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

NOTE: `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, by default.  By changing it to `FALSE`, can avoid doing the multiple `as.character` conversions after the dataset is created

Comment: it works too`ifelse(dt$A == lag(dt$A), as.character(lag(dt$B)), as.character(dt$A))` thanks